# PHP How to convert large txt file to csv and force download

Tags: php, csv

I have large txt file(1GB), and allow user to download with 2 formats, TXT and CSV

I create download.php file.

```
$file = $_GET['file'];
$type= $_GET['type'];
$pathfile = "/some/path/".$file.".txt";
$isifile = file_get_contents($pathfile);
    if($type == "TXT"){
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'.txt"');
        header('Content-type: text/plain');
        echo $isifile;
    }else if($type == "CSV"){
        $arr_file = explode("\n", $isifile); //will die here because array need large memory
        header("Content-type: application/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file.".csv");
        foreach($arr_file as $wd ){
            echo $wd;
        }
    }
```

The code is work for small txt file.

But it not work for large file.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just use readfile()?

Comment: Not working how? What do your logs say? It's likely a memory issue (reading in a file that big) or an execution time issue (script times out before the download is finished).

Comment: The script is probably breaking simply because of the file's sheer size. The infinitely better approach would be to convert the files once, and then link to the static file downloads instead of a PHP script

Comment: With a file that massive, why don't you convert the .txt file to a static .csv file then push that to the browser?

Comment: @jszobody PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8388608 bytes) in /var/www/html/download.php on line 10

Comment: @Aby Well there you go, you can't read that big of a file into memory, without bumping up your PHP memory limit (which only kicks the can down the road a bit). Look at `readfile()` as others are suggesting.

Comment: Thanks jszobody, now I prefer to use readfile() than file_get_contents() and it work well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a function named [readfile](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) that echoes the contents of a file to the output buffer *without loading the entire file into memory at the same time* -- you should use that for the TXT variant instead of file_get_contents/echo.

For the CSV version, you should use fopen to open the file and then [fgets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) to read it, line by line, and echo the converted content to the output buffer.  The code for that might look something like this...

```
$fileObj = fopen( $pathfile, "rt" );
while ( ( $line = fgets( $fileObj ) ) ) // by default this will read one line at a time
{
    //  If you need to do anything to transform this data to CSV format, convert each line here.
    echo $line;
}
```

Please accept my condolences for the downvotes you are likely to receive for poorly wording your question.

Answer (score 0):

https://superuser.com/questions/581702/how-can-i-convert-a-txt-file-to-csv-format-without-using-excel

apparently you can just rename it by changing the file extension if it is formatted correctly